# laravel route resource update method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm work on create to-do app in laravel with JWt 
all method (index,store,show ..etc) in route resource works well except update 
in result its work well and get success response but its not change in database

** sorry my english is not good

### this is my short codes

> api.php

```
    Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/todo', 'API\TodoController');
});
```

> BaseController.php

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function sendResponse($result,$message)
    {
        $response=[
            'success'=> true,
            'date' => $result,
            'message'=> $message
        ];
         return response()->json($response,200);
    }

    public function sendError($error,$errorMessages=[],$code=404)
    {
        $response=[
            'success'=> false,
            'message'=> $error
        ];

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $response['date']=$errorMessages;
        }
         return response()->json($response,$code);
    }}
```

> TodoController.php

```
class TodoController extends BaseController
{
    .
    .
    .

public function update(Request $request, Todolist $todolist)
    {

        //
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [

            'title' => 'required | max:255',
            'content' => 'required | max:255',
            'status' => 'required | max:2',
            'start_date' => 'required  ',
            'end_date' => 'required  ',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return $this->sendError('error validation', $validator->errors());

        }

        $todolist->title = $request->title;
        $todolist->content = $request->content;
        $todolist->status = $request->status;
        $todolist->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $todolist->end_date = $request->end_date;
        $todolist->save();
        return $this->sendResponse($todolist->toArray(), 'update successfully');

    }}
```

this is results in postman

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oHqC.png

Comment: Please, add postman result.

Comment: sorry , you can find it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oHqC.png

Comment: insted of put use patch

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta 
I got this error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field &#039;user_id&#039; doesn&#039;t have a default value (SQL: insert into `todolists` (`title`, `content`, `status`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (learn laravel api UPDATE, watch tutorial for learning laravel api UPDATE, 0, 2018-11-02, 2019-12-02, 2018-10-22 13:06:20, 2018-10-22 13:06:20))

Comment: can you share your todo model details and also database table

Comment: write `dd($todolist)` at first line in your function and show me the outeput

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta  https://imgur.com/a/5H4rjkS

Answer (score 2):

You should refer Model before class

```
use App\Todolist;
class TodoController extends BaseController
{
    .
    .
    .

public function update(Request $request, Todolist $todolist)
    {

        //
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [

            'title' => 'required | max:255',
            'content' => 'required | max:255',
            'status' => 'required | max:2',
            'start_date' => 'required  ',
            'end_date' => 'required  ',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return $this->sendError('error validation', $validator->errors());

        }


        $todolist->title = $request->title;
        $todolist->content = $request->content;
        $todolist->status = $request->status;
        $todolist->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $todolist->end_date = $request->end_date;
        $todolist->save();
        return $this->sendResponse($todolist->toArray(), 'update successfully');

    }}
```

Comment: it is insert or update? if update, you should find a record you wanna by using where condition and then try to update again.

Comment: I got this error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field &#039;user_id&#039; doesn&#039;t have a default value (SQL: insert into todolists (title, content, status, start_date, end_date, updated_at, created_at) values (learn laravel api UPDATE, watch tutorial for learning laravel api UPDATE, 0, 2018-11-02, 2019-12-02, 2018-10-22 13:06:20, 2018-10-22 13:06:20))

Comment: it is update how can use it? $todolist = TodoLIst::find($id) ?

Answer (score 0):

> TodoList.php Model

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Todolist extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='todolists';
    protected $fillable =[
        'title',
        'content',
        'status',
        'photo_id',
        'date_id',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'user_id'
    ];
}
```

> todo table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGr5Q.png